# Ajax return data compare with the data of text field is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

In the ajax return data it will return the user record given like below:-

```
Array(6)
 0:{_id: 1, provider: "abc", time: null, email_id: "abc@gmail.com"}
 1:{_id: 2, provider: "abc", time: null, email_id: "abcd@gmail.com"}
 2:{_id: 3, provider: "abc", time: null, email_id: "abcde@gmail.com"}
 3:{_id: 4, provider: "xyz", time: null, email_id: "xyz@gmail.com"}
 4:{_id: 5, provider: "dea", time: null, email_id: "dea@gmail.com"}
 5:{_id: 6, provider: "bcmc", time: null, email_id: "bcmc@abc.com"}
```

The above data is returned by the ajax and using loop I'm processing it and compare it with the text field data it is possible with the `if else` condition given below:-

Code

```
value_field = $('#provider_field').val();
$.ajax({
        url:"/api/v1/provider",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response.response)
            for (var i = 0; i < response.response.data.length; i++) {
            console.log(response.response.data[i].provider === value_field);
            if (response.response.data[i].provider === value_field){
                $('#search').append("<option value = "+response.response.data[i]._id+">"+response.response.data[i].provider+"</option>");
            counter = 1;
            }else{
                counter = 0;
                //here I want to remove
            }
        }
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="provider_field" id="provider_field" value="" placeholder="Enter the Provider name">
<select id= "search">
</select>
```

## Problem

- if the item has the same provider as `value_field` I would like to append an  to `#search`. if it is not matched any provider or wrong provider, I would like to empty the select option.

Help me to solve this.

Comment: Remove **break;** from your if else statement

Comment: when I remove `break;` then it will run but don't empty the select option on false @AlpeshJikadra

Comment: @TakitIsy  help me to solve this

Answer (score 1):

You have added **break;** statement in your if else is the problem.

Just remove the break statement from if else statement

You can clear all the option on getting response of the ajax, check the below update code.

```
$.ajax({
        url:"/api/v1/provider",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response.response);
//Below line will clear all the previous options
            $('#search').find('option').remove();
            for (var i = 0; i < response.response.data.length; i++) {
            console.log(response.response.data[i].provider === value_field);
            if (response.response.data[i].provider === value_field){
                $('#search').append("<option value = "+response.response.data[i]._id+">"+response.response.data[i].provider+"</option>");

                //break;

            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: it is not working. In my data base there are six data I saved from one i searched but for other counter will false then it will not appending the data to the select option.

Comment: You have a `remove()` in `$('#search').find('option').remove()` was that intentional? Please describe your problem better if you want others to be able to help you

Comment: @chada What would you like to remove? The last appended <option> ?

Comment: @DanyKhalife see if I entered the last record provider name then it will append it into the option but if I entered the third option or fourth option then it will not append to the select option.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not making sense to me. Can you try to word your question like this:
if the item has the same provider as `value_field` I would like to `append an <option>` to `#search`
if it is not, I would like to `.....`

Comment: also it will make things easier if you can add your HTML

Comment: @DanyKhalife see now I edit it again. Now you understand what I want to say?

Comment: @chada, Hi I have updated the answer could you please check it.

Answer (score 0):

```
value_field = $('#provider_field').val();
$.ajax({
       url: "/api/v1/provider",
       type: "GET",
       dataType: 'json',
       async: false,
      success: function(response) {
               console.log(response.response)
               for (var i = 0; i < response.response.data.length; i++) {
                  console.log(response.response.data[i].provider === value_field);
                 if (response.response.data[i].provider === value_field) {
                       $('#search').append("<option value = " + response.response.data[i]._id + ">" + response.response.data[i].provider + "</option>");
                      counter = 1;
                } else {
                     counter = 0;
                    //here I want to remove
                   $("#search option[value='" + response.response.data[i]._id + "']").remove();
                   } // end of else
               }// end of id
          }// end of for
});// end of ajax
```